# seaborn: countplot rotation and formatting to decimal places

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to both rotate (45 degrees) and narrow the xticks (to 2 decimal places) of my countplot in seaborn. But unfortunately I can't get it to work.

This is my code:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

wine_data = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', sep=';')
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=45)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
sns.countplot(data=wine_data, x='alcohol', ax=ax1)
```

You can download the data-set [here](https://github.com/DavidMeerkatRefaeli/test/blob/master/winequality-white.csv).

And this is the result:
[image]

As you can see rotation works, but the formatting doesn't.

Comment: You don't provide a  [mcve] here. But I would assume that `countplot` overwrites the formatter you set.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - it is now reproducible.

Comment: I don't think one needs winequality data to reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure `countplot()` is the right kind of plot for your data? `countplot` is meant to be used with categorical data, whereas "alcohol content" is a continuous value. Seems to me you are trying to plot a histogram, or `sns.distplot()` if you really want to use seaborn?

In any case, your problem stems from the fact that it is a categorical plot, and therefore each tick represent a category as a string, and not as a float as you would expect given your data. To fix the rounding of the numbers, you therefore need to extract those string, convert them back into numbers and round them as you convert them back again in strings...

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
sns.countplot(data=wine_data, x='alcohol', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xticklabels(['{:.2f}'.format(float(t.get_text())) for t in ax1.get_xticklabels()])
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=45)
```

[image]

Comment: The data is not important (just following a course), and you're right it's probably doesn't make sense to use countplot here.

Comment: I just noticed that the formatter starts counting them from 0 to 102. This is not what I want, I want to cut the decimal place after 2 digits.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice the different numbers. This is due to the fact that it's a categorical plot, so the labels are probably strings that are replaced by the underlying tick position when you change the formatter. I'll have another crack at it later.

Comment: I've modified my answer with a solution that (hopefully) actually works this time